# How to add WCF templates to Visual Studio Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, wcf, visual-studio-express

I am working through the book Learning WCF by Michele Bustamante, and trying to do it using Visual Studio C# Express 2008.  The instructions say to use WCF project and item templates, which are not included with VS C# Express.  There *are* templates for these types included with Visual Studio Web Developer Express, and I've tried to copy them over into the right directories for VS C# Express to find, but the IDE doesn't find them.  Is there some registration process? Or config file somewhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have both Visual Web Developer (VWD) 2008 and Visual C# (VC#) 2008 installed you can copy templates between them.  The VWD template files live in (by default):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress
```

The VC# templates live in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VCSExpress
```

Simply copy the templates between the two directories, they might not match exactly but they should be close enough to make sense, for instance I copied the project templates from VC# into VWD by copying files from:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VCSExpress\ProjectTemplates\1033
```

into:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033
```

The templates won't appear straight away in the template browser.  For VWD you need to run:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress.exe /installvstemplates
```

For VC# you run:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VCSExpress.exe /installvstemplates
```

Comment: Absurdly obscure. But at least there's a way to add templates in C# express.

Comment: This will also work for the Windows Phone version of C# express, the only difference is the executable:
C:\Windows\system32>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7
\IDE\VPDExpress.exe" /installvstemplates

Answer (score 4):

If you are a student you could get the full Visual Studio 2008 from [DreamSpark](http://dreamspark.com) for free.

Answer (score 4):

Mike,

Visual Web Developer 2008 Express will help you in working with WCF Projects.

I have the following...

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Hope this helps.

Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

As a be aware follow-up, I also had to run

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress.exe /ResetSettings

**After** copying the templates and running the

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress.exe /installvstemplats

The IDE was crashing when it tried to enumerate the C# project templates tree. After running the ResetSettings, the tree iterated and the new templates were present.