# Visual C# 2010 Express - no WCF project template

Tags: wcf, visual-c#-express-2010

I can't see any template to start a WCF project (I do see ones for WPF amongst other things). Is this because I don't need a template, or because it's missing in Express, or because I'm looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to add WCF templates to Visual Studio Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110451/how-to-add-wcf-templates-to-visual-studio-express) - although that question relates to VS2008 it may help.

Comment: I can confirm that the steps given in the accepted answer still work for the VS 2010 Express editions.

Answer (score 1):

It's a template in the Web Developer version.

"WCF RIA Services Class Library" and "WCF Service Application" are both listed there.

I think I understand why Microsoft are packaging the WCF projects with the Web Developer version but it an arbitrary distinction. I can't see why they don't include them in both applications.

Comment: web developer? I want to write a proper app :) I dislike MS trying to brand WCF and development in general as being all about web-services.

Comment: @John - I agree it seems like an arbitrary split and I can't really see why it can't be in both. See the question linked to by @Stuart to see if that approach will still with the 2010 versions.