# Can't use WCF templates in Visual Studio Express

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, templates

I've used the Visual Studio 2010 Express All-In-One to install Visaul C# and Visual Web Developer.

Once I opened Visual C# and tried to create a WCF Application, I couldn't find it.

After looking on internet I found a tip to do it on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110451/how-to-add-wcf-templates-to-visual-studio-express).

I have done exactly like the guy explained, and now I have `WCFServiceProject`.

[image: WCF]

Now everything seems to be correct, `but` when I try to create a WCF project I get this error

[image: Error]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have the option to create a WCF Application in Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Comment: And what is the solution in this case ?

Comment: I guess you'll have to get a Professional edition 2010. It works for 2008, I tried it before. But I don't think WCF will work on 2010 Express.

Comment: Try updating Windows SDK to Windows 7 SDK v7.1, and running VWD in Administrator mode. It might work.

Answer (score 5):

Using Visual Studio Express, you have to explicitly start **Visual Web Developer Express** to create a project of type *WCF Service Application*.

Visual C# Express even doesn't allow to add existing WCF projects to an existing solution.

If your installation doesn't offer this type of project from the (default) installed project types you should check your installation options.