# Learning WCF - Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am new to WCF and I am using "Learning WCF: A Hands-on Guide" book for now. The book has used VS2008 for the examples, and I am not sure what Visual Studio IDE to use for the examples. I tried using VS Express for Web and it gives the following error:

> "HelloIndigo.exe does not contain static Main method suitable at entry point'.

I can understand the cause of the issue, but I am not sure where to add the main method. So I used VS Express for Desktop and it worked fine, but as I kept going in the first chapter I could not proceed as there are no WCF service templates in the VS Express for Desktop version. VS2012 is available only in trial version for free, and it expires in 90 days. So what IDE should I should be using?  If the answer is VS Express for Web, then how to fix the error for the example in first chapter?
The example provided in the book is
Host:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Host
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloIndigo.HelloIndigoService),new Uri("http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo")))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(HelloIndigo.IHelloIndigoService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "HelloIndigoService");
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Please <ENTER> to terminate the service host");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

HelloIndigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace HelloIndigo
{
 public class HelloIndigoService : IHelloIndigoService
 {
    public string HelloIndigo()
    {
        return "Hello Indigo";
    }
}
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.thatindigogirl.com/samples/2006/06")]
public interface IHelloIndigoService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string HelloIndigo();
}
```

}

Client:
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Client
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo/HelloIndigoService");
        IHelloIndigoService proxy = ChannelFactory<IHelloIndigoService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), ep);
        string s = proxy.HelloIndigo();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine("Please <ENTER> to terminate client");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

ServiceProxy.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Client
{
class ServiceProxy
{
}
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.thatindigogirl.com/samples/2006/06")]
public interface IHelloIndigoService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string HelloIndigo();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post some code so we can take a look?  All programs need a main method. So if you don't have one then you won't be able to debug the application you're writing since it cannot start on its own otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use WCF templates in Visual Studio Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795522/cant-use-wcf-templates-in-visual-studio-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HelloIndigo` should be compiled as a library (DLL) and not an executable. So there should be no `Main` method - it doesn't have one as a class library.

The point of the `Host` is that it will host the service library `HelloIndigo` and start listening for calls on an endpoint for that particular service.

Change `HelloIndigo` to compile as a class library and add a reference to `HelloIndigo` in `Host`. Then start up the `Host` process.