# How to include WCF in Microsoft Visual C# Express 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio, visual-c#-express-2010

I need to use WCF in Microsoft Visual C# Express. I found the following Link which shows how to copy and use the templates:
 [How to add WCF templates to Visual Studio Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110451/how-to-add-wcf-templates-to-visual-studio-express) .  But I have only the express edition of Microsoft Visual C#; I don't have Visual Studio, so I am unable to copy the templates. I tried to install **Web Developer Express**, but installation fails. 
Is there any other way to include the WCF in Microsoft Visual C#?

Comment: As long as you have the appropriate assemblies (like `System.ServiceModel`) you can create WCF services.  You don't need the template to do it, it just makes it easier.

Comment: If you look more closely at the question you linked above, I think you could get it to work.  The comments say that it woks in VCE 2010.